# network error when attempting to fetch resource Type error

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm trying to fetch the NYT API, it worked just fine, I tried adding it to a function so the user can call the fetching function when clicking the button, I get this error **TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource**, I've tried looking it up but all the answers are unrelated, function :

```
    const keywordVal = document.getElementById("keyword").value
    fetch("https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=" + keywordVal + "&api-key=apikey")
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => {
            let count = 0;
            const articleArray = data.response.docs;

            for (const articles of articleArray) {
                const headlines = articles.headline.main;
                var ArticleLinks = articles.web_url
                count += 1
                createElement("h4", count + "." + "<p>" + headlines + "</p>")
                createElement("a", ArticleLinks + "<hr> ", ArticleLinks)
                console.log(ArticleLinks)

            }

        })
        .catch(err => { console.log(`Error : ${err}`) });
}
```

Comment: maybe check your apikey again?

Comment: @spooky_sec thanks this solved it